# Host multi subdomain using Gorilla Mux

Tags: go, gorilla

How can I host multi subdomain with Gorilla Mux?

```
https://www.izzat.com/api/v1/user/get
```

```
https://auth.izzat.com/api/v2/get
```

What I have tried:

```
func NewHttpServer(l logger.Logger, c config.Config, routes []Routes, r *mux.Router) *Http {

        r.Use(middleware.LoggingMiddleware(l))

        v1 := r.Host("www.izzat.com").PathPrefix("/api/v1/").Subrouter()

        for _, route := range routes {
                route.InitRoutes(v1)
        }

        v2 := r.Host("auth.izzat.com").PathPrefix("/api/v2/").Subrouter()
  v2.HandleFunc("/get", Test)

        spa1 := SpaHandler{
                IndexPath:  "index.html",
                StaticPath: "web/dist",
        }

        r.PathPrefix("/").Handler(spa1)

        return &Http{
                logger: l,
                config: c,
        }
}
```

I'm using reverse proxy to the `izzat.com` domain. My nginx config:

```
server {
        listen 80;
        listen [::]:80;
        server_name *.izzat.com;

        access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
        error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;

        #ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/izzat.com/fullchain.pem;
        #ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/izzat.com/privkey.pem;
        #include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf;
        #ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem;

        location / {
                proxy_pass http://myserver.hostname:3000;
        }
}
```

Comment: I have questions
[1] What happened at the current code, when executing it? [2] Is there no problem when it comes to resolving domain names of `www.izzat.com` and `auth.izzat.com`?

Comment: @nimdrak It can load the page and it serve the static assets, if I redirect to `www.izzat.com` or `auth.izzat.com` it shows the same pages, but the route does not work.